# Detect touchmove on circle in svg element

Tags: javascript, html, svg, touchscreen

I made a website that displays an SVG element (embedded in the HTML) and want to allow users to connect dots (`<circle>` elements) in it by dragging with their mouse or finger over them.

By listening to the `mousedown` and `mouseover` events and adding `line` elements to the SVG this works perfectly on the desktop.

I added listeners to `touchstart`, `touchmove`, `touchend` and `touchcancel` but I ran into issues. 
It seems like `touchmove` is never triggered on Google Chrome on my Android phone and on Google Chrome on my Android tablet it is only triggered when I remove my finger.

**Edit:** Here's my code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s5vcfzbq/ You can drag with your mouse from circle to circle to connect them, but it doesn't work on touch screens.

Comment: Probably best if you can have a runnable demo running here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [InteractJS](http://interactjs.io/) to handle touch events. It doesn't have any dependencies and handles dragging, rotation and multitouch etc.

```
interact('.drag-and-resize').draggable({
   snap: {
   targets: [
    { x: 100, y: 200 },
    function (x, y) { return { x: x % 20, y: y }; }
   ]}
}).resizable({
    inertia: true
});
```

Here is a demo I cobbled together on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/sidonaldson/pen/GqKZXm) using SVGs

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple workaround (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56197907/touch-events-are-wrong-for-transformed-svg-elements/#answer-65777666)):

Add a `'touchstart'` eventListener to the container `<svg>` element with a noop handler:

```js
document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('touchstart', () => {});
```

Now your `<circle>` elements should trigger touch events reliably.